# Dynamically assign a synthetic record to Google Domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, google-domains

I own a domain on Google Domains.

I want to create subdomains for my projects dynamically.

For example:

```
My Domain:
https://adomain.example

Subdomain:
https://project-name.adomain.example

Where the subdomain redirects you to:
https://project-name.example
```

So when a user navigates to `https://project-name.adomain.example` - they will be redirected to a completely different website, hosted elsewhere (`https://project-name.example`).

I know I can achieve this by creating a `Synthetic Record` via the Google Domains DNS menu:
[image: screenshot of the Google domains synthetic record DNS menu]

But I have to manually navigate to the Google Domains dashboard and input my values there.

I was able to find the following question which shows that you can pass credentials via a URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544160/how-can-you-change-the-ttl-value-of-a-google-domain-synthetic-record

I'm not confident about passing my username & password in plain text via a URL to create a synthetic record.

Is there any other way of achieving this? Any resources I can have a look at? An API of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically implement this functionality using wildcard subdomains.   Rather than point each subdomain at your server individually, you would point **all** subdomains ato your server and let your web application determine how to handle them.

From a DNS perspective, that would be implementing a record like:

```
*.adomain.example CNAME adomain.example
```

or

```
*.adomain.example A x.x.x.x
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the IP address of your server.

Then on your webserver you would set up a wildcard virtual host.  See on Stack Overflow: [Virtualhost For Wildcard Subdomain and Static Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758351/virtualhost-for-wildcard-subdomain-and-static-subdomain).   The web app software on that virtual host would examine the requested subdomain and either isssue the required redirect, or return a "404 Not Found" error.